# Split using regexp with exceptions, avoid a rewrite of Split function

Tags: c#, regex, split

I want to use regexp to split a set of lines except when the comma is preceding with a dash.

This is the problem line:

```
    Likör, Choklad-, kaffe- och nötter
```

The resulting split should look like this:

```
    Likör
    Choklad-, kaffe- och nötter
```

Test data:

```
Punsch
Rosé
Mousserande vin, Rosé
Röda, Fruktigt & Smakrikt
Likör, Choklad-, kaffe- och nötter
Likör, Grädde och ägg
Vita, Lätt & Avrundat
```

Each line is going through the Split function by itself.
The language is C# if that helps and the function I'm using is

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split
```

I have never been able to grasp regexp. Regexps tried:

```
@"[^-],"    
@"(,)(?!-)" 
@"[^-][,]"  
@"(?!-,),"  
@"[?:^-][,]"
@"^-,|[,]"  
@"[^-](?:,)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this pattern using negative look-behind

```
(?<!-),
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/189)

Comment: I think you are missing a space at the end of the pattern (i.e. after the comma).  Without a space at the end, the second string in the split result starts with a space unlike the OP's sample output.